# Real asynchronous javascript function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Does

```
setTimeout(function () { /*logic*/ }, 0);
```

Really makes the function to be asynchronous?

Comment: [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

Comment: What it really does is pause javascript execution to allow for the other browser events (such as loading the DOM) to catch up. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful

Comment: @KernelPanik That is not exactly true. The execution does not get paused. The function is queued on the browser's Event Queue.

Comment: @Abhishek: What exactly is your understanding of "*asynchronous*"? The answer could be both yes and no :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not.

It just places the function on the event queue with the given delay (here a delay of zero). If there are any other functions currently queued up for execution, it gets placed behind them and has to wait until those (including the currently active) functions are executed.

To test this, you could do something like ethis

```
console.log( 'start' );
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("timeout");
}, 0);

// some very long running code 
console.log( 'end' );
```

You will still get the output:

> start
>
> end
>
> timeout

Answer (score 4):

No, it *does not* make the function asynchronous - if the function takes some time it will still block the thread.

However, `setTimeout` puts this function onto the Browser's Event Queue. So it will be executed after all other events which are already on that queue and are waiting to get executed (and would be executed *after* your scriptblock is finished if you weren't using the timeout).

To be precise, `setTimeout(xxx,0)` does make no sense, the minimum delay is 4ms, as stated [in the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers).

Altogether the timing is a bit more complex than I explained here, but this might be sufficient as toplevel explanation;) For more info, check [John Resig's Article](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly

```
console.log("1");
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("2");
}, 0);
console.log("3");
```

You'll probably see the output...

```
1
3
2
```

The timeout will not block the execution of the code but ALL browsers enforce a minimum timeout delay.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit difficult to explain whole javascript timer thing. May be this will help you.

[John Resig Blog: How does Javascript timers work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)